# I want to create a cart view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want to create a cartview by allowing an item to be selected once I click on the Icon Button then the item is pushed to the cartview and it can show if the item is clicked again that it has been added to the cart.
I would want only when the Icon Button is clicked that's when the item should be added.

Then I want the cartview to automatically calculate prices and everything together

The issue is I don't know how to get the data which I stored in a model in the app. Like I want to interact between the model and the code for the cartview

Comment: In your question you just describe what you want to do, but you don't say what problem you're facing.
Please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to create more descriptive questions.

Comment: I want to like link my data filled in the model with the information the cart view wants

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide enough useful information, you imagine being asked by someone else the same question as you are asking and asking you to answer, how would you answer? as @GuilhermeGabanelli mentioned, learn how to ask a good question or at least one the right way